# Anaconda prompt: running python in prompt vs jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda, conda

I am running into some issues with packages I can access in anaconda prompt vs what is available in Jupyter Notebook.

I recently created an environment for python 3.6. I installed a few packages, including pandas, using:

```
    conda install pandas
```

And all is well: 
[image: anaconda prompt]

When I check conda list, I also see pandas installed for py36.

```
    conda list
```

Now, I run the following line to start my jupyter notebook from this same location:

```
    jupyter notebook
```

I then run into an error when I try to import pandas. I then try to install pandas with no luck.

[image: py3.6]

My guess is this stems from having downloaded anaconda for python 2.7, but I assume there is a way to get things working in both versions of python for jupyter notebook.

To add, I am able to use pandas when I use python 2.7 (referred to as "root"):

```
    activate root
    jupyter notebook
```

[image: py2.7]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you saying you have two different Anaconda versions installed? That sounds like a source of trouble - maybe you're running the wrong version of `activate` and/or `jupyter`. Maybe check your `PATH` and/or remove older version of Anaconda - you can use both Python 2.x and 3.x environments with the same Anaconda version.

Comment: Okay that is helpful. One thing I did notice is I have both python 2 & 3 available in root, and still have an issue with pandas when I try to run in the python 3 notebook.